# Selenium Grid Automatic Parallelization

Tags: python, testing, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver

I am trying to run Selenium tests in parallel. They are written in Python with unittest, and they communicate with a hub that is connected to several WebDrivers.

What is the best practice for writing tests in this configuration? Is it better to have a lot of test methods within one `unittest.TestCase` class, or is it better to create many of there classes instead? For now all my tests are in one class, and since `driver.close()` doesn't get called until the end of the test case, I gain no parallelization. Is it possible to achieve parallelization without an additional testing framework like testNG?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need something beyond basic unittest that supports parallel execution. Maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools

Each paralleled thread will need its own instance of webdriver, so you are going to need to take care of that before you move any further with parallelization.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was planning on spawning a hub/server, and connecting N WebDrivers to it each on a separate machine, where N is the parallelization factor. is it possible to connect directly to the webdrivers without the hub, and if so, is that what you meant?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need an instance of your "driver" variable you are using for "driver.close()" for each thread. Two threads cannot share the same instance of driver.

having multiple connections to the same hub is fine, but each connection must be separate.

Comment: I use spring ThreadLocalTargetSource for this task in java and it works great and manages everything for me. if you implement everything by hand you need to replace 

    driver.close()

with 

    for each driver in driverPool[] {driver.close}